# The navagation Toggle Wont show up

Tags: javascript, html, css

Any problem with this code it wont show when I tried to click the toggle icon in responsive view in console it says:

> navTogglerBtn is null

I tried to look at it but I can't find the problem. Im new in JavaScript. Thank you so much heres my code in JSFiddle [code is here](https://jsfiddle.net/wkho7zu8/1/)

```
const navTogglerBtn = document.querySelector(".nav-toggler"),
      aside = document.querySelector(".aside-menu");

navTogglerBtn.addEventListener("click",() => {
    asideSectionTogglerBtn();
})

function asideSectionTogglerBtn() {
    aside.classList.toggle("open");
    navTogglerBtn.classList.toggle("open");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You CSS code is wrong. It's `.nav-toggler.open` not `.nav-toggler .open`. And apply some transition to have smooth effect.

```css
.aside-menu .nav-toggler {
    display: flex;
    left: 30px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.aside-menu {
    left: -270px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.aside-menu .nav-toggler.open {
    left: 300px;
}
.aside-menu.open {
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: While you're right about that, it doesn't solve the OP's problem of the JavaScript error `navTogglerBtn is null`

Comment: Thanks on that answer, but as Gnanavel said still the navTogglerBtn is null

Comment: I don't get any null value.The problem I think is you are loading your script before your html code that is in head tag.Try putting your JS code after writing all your html code.